# How can I parse XML in WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xml-parsing

How to parser this xml content.

```
<Content>    
    <caption> Today Headline </caption>        
    <s1>        
        <name>6</name>
        <name>4</name>
        <name>4</name>        
    </s1>            
    <s2>        
        <name>3</name>
        <name>6</name>
        <name>0</name>        
    </s2>    
</Content>
```

Mycode:

```
date = (from story 
        in xmlParser.Descendants("s1")
        select new EspnViewModel
        {
            Category = story.Element("name").Value,

        }).ToList();
        return data;
```

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to parse everything out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont you use xmlParser.Descendants("name") instead?

EDIT:

var caption = xmlParser.Descendants("caption").First().InnerText;

var names = from story in xmlParser.Descendants("name")
select new EspnViewModel
{
    Category = story.InnerText
}).ToList();

Note: I am writing this in haste, but you get the idea..

Comment: see the question, how to get caption ,s1,s2 tell me idea to do that

Comment: which value can i return here. caption or names

Comment: Either one. If you need two object.. then wrap them in another object.. Or you can use out keyword for caption since its plain text.. and return the list...

Answer (score 0):

```
private List<yourclass> ReadList()
{
    using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            if (myIsolatedStorage.FileExists("xmlName.xml"))
            {
                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile("xmlName.xml", FileMode.Open))
                {
                    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<your class>));
                    List<yourclass> data = (List<yourclass>)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
                    return data.ToList();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure he is reading from IsolatedStorage? The author didnt mention that anywhere..

Comment: I am using xml how to get caption,s1,s2 values. Hey what is this xmlName.xml?

Comment: In that code snippet the xml will be parsed form a local xml file. If you are getting the xml data as a response from web request you pls skip that line of code and use it as a stream input. you will get the desired o/p. or else you can use Descendant parsing mechanism.